# Lollipop inconsistent CPU usage on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, systrace

I'm developing a game for Android and am primarily testing it on the Samsung Galaxy S4.
However, I'm finding that since I've installed Lollipop (5.0.1) on it that my game is now occasionally freezing for approx. 200ms every so often, causing it to drop around 10 frames.

The game has also been tested on multiple other (non-S4) devices also running Lollipop and it is not doing this.
Going by the CPU usage monitor in Android Studio, I'm having the complete opposite to the more common (upward) spikes in CPU usage. I'm finding that the CPU usage is spiking *down* instead of up.

[image: CPU usage spikes]

Is this a common problem with Lollipop/Galaxy S4?
Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to find out what is causing this?

Comment: You can give systrace a try: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look and see whether I can find anything.